# Specifically ordering products in a woocommerce shortcode

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm using the shortcode [products ids="1094,2811,1097,1095,1098"] for a widget. The products need to appear in the exact order I've listed them, which is different to the order they have to appear in the store, so I wouldn't be able to drag and drop the product order.

None of the 'orderby' options I've found [here](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-shortcodes/#) seem to allow that.

Are there any ways to work around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that without extra functions / plugins but you can change the default order to use the 'Menu order' -> Go to WooCommerce > Settings. On the Products tab, under the Display settings, ensure that Default Product Sorting is set to “Default sorting (custom ordering + name)”. You can then edit the order value in the Product Data > Advanced tab on the product edit page.

Comment: Thanks. The default order needs to stay different since the client wants it one order on the store page but a different order on the widget I'm building. It didn't appear to be (easily) possible but I just wondered if I was missing something obvious.

Answer (score 4):

Well, it turns out, you can do it very easily without additional coding.

`[products]` shortcode uses [WP_Query](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/) call which accepts also `post__in` as a value for `orderby` option which does exactly what you need. So even though this option is not mentioned in woocommerce docs, it works.

```
[products ids="257,233,269" orderby="post__in"]
```